# Display months with two-digits and with month names in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a loop to display months in a form.

**I want to display months in two different formats**:

1. With **two digits** like this: **01, 02, 03**...
2. With **plain text** like this: **January, February**...

Just like this:

```
<option value="01">January</option>
<!-- ... -->
<option value="12">December</option>
```

The problem is, I can't manage to display this.

**Here is my code so far:**

```
echo '<select name="month">';

for ($x=1; $x<=12; $x++)
{
    $val=strlen($x);

    if($val==1)
    {
        echo '<option value="'.'0'.$x.'">'.'0'.$x.'</option>';
    } else {
        echo '<option value="'.$x.'">'.$x.'</option>';
}
}

echo '</select>';
```

Comment: [This article](http://gilbert.pellegrom.me/php-month-number-to-month-name-the-easy-way/) shows you how. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### To output the months on two-digits

You have two main choices:

1. `str_pad()` - see [PHP documentation here](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.str-pad.php)
2. `sprintf()` - see [PHP documentation there](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.sprintf.php)

You would use the two like that, assuming `$x` is your numerical month (1, 2, 3...):

```
// with str_pad()
$month = str_pad($x, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

// with sprintf()
$month = sprintf('%02d', $x);
```

### To output the month as a name

For the literal month part, you can use the `DateTime` class ([see PHP doc](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.datetime.php)).

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $x);
$monthName = $date->format('F');
```

### The two running together

It goes like this in your case, with `str_pad()`:

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++)
{
    $month = str_pad($x, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $x);
    $monthName = $date->format('F');

    echo '<option value="'.$month.'">'.$monthName.'</option>';
}
```

Comment: can you explain how str_pad function?

Comment: This is a partial answer and really doesn't pertain to the question asked, it is a suggestion. OP is asking how to get the month text from the number.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn totally right - my mistake, I'm going to edit my answer

Comment: I got this Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\xampplite\htdocs\app\option.php on line 300

Comment: mmm... this error has nothing to do with the code above (neither in your question, nor in my answer) - it's an error you have while trying to read data from MySQL - you should fetch your results before using them as an array

Comment: @Jivan I tried only your code but I got this Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Comment: That means you have fed data to `DateTime::createFromFormat` that it doesn’t understand, so that you don’t get a DateTime object but just false back from that line. You should go fix your MySQL errors first and see to it that you get the _correct_ data.

Comment: @user3097736 ok I had a typo in my code. It should be fixed now :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `str_pad()` and `mktime()` you can do this

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++) {
    $monthNum = str_pad($x, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNum, 10));
    echo '<option value='.$monthNum.'">'.$monthName.'</option>';
}
```